# Jupyter notebook will not import matplotlib although it appears to be installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

in:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df.plot()
```

Gives:

```
ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting.
```

I installed matplotlib through pip, and showing it gives:

```
Location: c:\users\miscs\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
```

in Jupyter, sys.executable outputs:

```
'C:\\Users\\miscs\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python.exe'
```

Why is this error occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: what happens when you execute a cell with this 

`import matplotlib`

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same error, resolved it thus:

I did `pip install matplotlib` in my virtualenv, and then I ran `import matplotlib` which succeeded, but the `df.plot()` step still gave me the `ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting.` error.

Saved my Jupyter notebook, killed and restarted the Jupyter notebook server, and reopened the notebook. Didn't face the error again.

I guess `matplotlib` needs to be installed and available *before* the notebook is started.